# Why did my SQL question disappear?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I asked a question 35 minutes ago which disappeared from my recent questions but shows in my recent activity. It had 4 answers but somehow magically it has come down to 2 now.

The question is available here

[SQL query for the following output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090957/sql-query-for-the-following-output)

It does not allow me to comment back and says the question was `deleted or locked`.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Your question is (as you've noted) still there, and it is not locked for me (the two answers you are missing have been deleted by their owners)

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem, you've multiple unregisted accounts. I'd recomment to register your account so that you can login using the same account from everywhere and keep a history of your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/users/469409/gaurav, http://stackoverflow.com/users/425340/gaurav and http://stackoverflow.com/users/473784/gaurav.

Answer (score 1):

1 - This belongs on the [meta site.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

2 - There were answers to your question that were deleted by  the answerer.